# How to add a background image to google maps markers?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, foursquare

I'm using foursquare API to show some places on a map. When I tried to render the icons in the categories some images give 404. Ex:

```
https://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/shops/mall.png
```

So I change the pattern to match this path that is the path that foursquare uses for it's icons:

```
https://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/shops/mall_32.png
```

The problem now is that these icons have transparent background (which looks confusing) and I want to know a way to attach these markers some kind of background.

Thanks!

PD: I don't want to use shadows because I read it's deprecated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS Maps v3: custom marker with user profile picture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965161/js-maps-v3-custom-marker-with-user-profile-picture)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google map markers are put in place as Canvas elements not DOM elements, and there's no direct equivalent of a background image.

You could try one of two things :

- Create your own marker image complete with a halo or background rectangle, then specify your image as the `icon` when marker(s) are created (see the [marker options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) section of the documentation).
- Create a general purpose `background` image with no foreground then, for each required marker create *two markers* positioned such that the foreground overlays the background.

The first approach is more efficient and would generally be preferred.

The second approach might be useful if you had many types of marker and wanted each of them to be set against the same background image. This would be inefficient in terms of client CPU and RAM but would save you time in preparing the artwork.

Comment: Thanks Beetroot! I thought the same solution a few hours I post this question, the first approach obviously. I download foursquare's category icons to my server and then (with Drupal) apply an imagestyle that has a marker in the background.